# Can someone explain me the meaning of nested pairs in Prolog’s list ?

Tags: prolog

I know that Prolog lists are not flat but they are nested pairs.. can someone explain to me what does actually mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say this about all Prolog implementations but generally speaking every list consists of `Head` and `Tail` (where `Head` is a list's element, and `Tail` is also a list), or it's empty and has neither `Head` nor `Tail`.

So a list `L = [a, b, c, d]` looks like this:

```
head(L) = a
tail(L) = [b, c, d]
```

Or,

```
[H | T] = [a | [b, c, d]]
```

So then `[b, c, d] = [b | [c, d]]`, `[c, d] = [c | [d]]`, and `[d] = [d | []]` where `[]` is an *empty list*.

Empty list, `[]`, is an exception to this and cannot be divided further.

Or in *tree* form:

```
*  - node
[] - empty list

  *
 / \
a   *
   / \
  b   *
     / \
    c   *
       / \
      d  []
```

Comment: @lurker, my answer is not about syntax, more of an idea behind lists in Prolog.

Comment: not 'every list' though; it's just a common implementation in Lisp-like languages, Prolog included.

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog, a non-empty list is natively represented using the `'.'` functor and two arguments. The first argument is the head, and the second the tail, which is itself a list:

```
'.'(Head, Tail).
```

Prolog also allows, for lists, an alternate syntax as follows:

```
[Head | Tail]
```

Again, `Tail` is itself a list or could be `[]` (the empty list). The term `[]` is a special *atom* that represents the empty list. You cannot represent an empty list with a `'.'` notation.

If you have a list of atoms, `a`, `b`, and `c`, it can be written in any of the following ways:

```
'.'(a, '.'(b, '.'(c, [])))
[a,b,c,d]
[a | [b,c,d]]
[a | [b | [c,d]]]
[a | [b | [c | [d]]]]
[a | [b | [c | [d | []]]]]
```

You can also have as many of the "front" elements as you wish in the head:

```
[a,b | [c,d]]
[a,b,c | [d]]
[a,b,c,d | []]
```

Based upon my description above, you should be able to see that this make sense.

If you use `write_canonical` you can see what Prolog's "native" representation is:

```
| ?- write_canonical([a,b,c]).
'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,[])))

yes
| ?- write_canonical([]).
[]

yes
| ?-
```

Now in SWI Prolog, they've recommissioned the dot (`'.'`) to mean something special, so the `write_canonical` will say that `[a,b,c]` is the canonical representation of `[a,b,c]`.